# Callback being executed twice in find.exec()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So, i have this code:

```
api.find = function(filter, sort, skip, limit){
    var callback = typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] === 'function'? arguments[arguments.length - 1]  : function(){};
    University.model.find(filter).sort(sort).skip(skip).limit(limit).exec(function(err, universities){
        console.log('callbacking api.find');
        callback(err, universities);
    })
};
```

and

```
controller.index = function(req, res){
    api.find(function(err, universities){
        console.log('callbacking controller.index');
        req.pageTitle = 'Universities';
        req.universities = universities;
        res.render('list.html', req);
    });

};
```

and

```
app.get('/universities/', controller.index);
```

when i load /universities i get the error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

the console.log in api.find is executed once but the one in controller.index is executed twice.

I have no other place where that index method is called, so i really don't understand this.

Comment: Try adding `res.end()` after the render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've called `api.find` with the callback as the first argument.  I see in the first line of `api.find` where you get this callback, but note that `filter == callback` after that.  You then pass filter to `University.model.find` as well as calling it in the callback to `exec`.  `University.model.find` interprets its last argument as a callback if it is a function, so it is called once from that and once from your callback to `exec`.

You need to be more careful about parsing out arguments; if you're going to interpret something as a callback, don't also use it as something else.